# Multiple sequence number generator for a single column while saving to the postgresql db

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a column (certificate number) in DB, wherein I have to save the value of certificate number for 3 different products, each products series starts from a different number (1st product series starts from 001, 2nd product starts with 2000 and so on so forth), I have to update the same column in the table from the previously saved certificate number of that particular product series.is there any way I can achieve this using spring boot, JPA, with PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do with **PostgreSQL** `SEQUENCE`.
First you create a set of required sequences, i.e.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE product1 START 1; // You may need to define max value as well
CREATE SEQUENCE product2 START 2000;
etc.
```

Then you can use `nextval(sequence_name)` in your SQL statements, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (nextval('product1'), 'bla-bla');
```

You can find more info here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createsequence.html

If you want to use **JPA**, then you need to look at two annotations.
In order to create a sequence for an entity you use

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="product2", initialValue=2000)
```

and on the field definition you use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="product2")
```

Edit: I see the issue you may have with JPA, you can't choose which sequence to use for an operation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's the requirement, i have made the block synchronized as well but the problem is when 100 threads of 10 processes are trying to update the column, it's throwing error